# Set focus to a button in a new TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, tabcontrol

I use a TabControl to display a list of items. The ItemView is a separate control I wrote.

```
       <TabControl SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ctrls:ItemView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortItemDescription}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

If the user presses a Button a new ViewModel is added to the list of ViewModels and the TabControl displays it as a new tab. After adding the new tab is selected.

```
       <Button Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}"
               Content="Add item"/>
```

Inside of the new View is a button that needs to be focused each time a new tab is added. I have tried to use the FocusManager and the Initialized event in the ItemView but these are only called for the first time I add a new tab.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ItemView"
         ...
         Initialized="ViewInitialized">
<Grid>
    ...

    <!-- Set focus to this button -->
    <Button Content="Search"
            Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
            Name="SearchButton"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

The content of the Initialize method in the ItemView is currently this one - which is working fine... *for the first time and then never again*

```
    public delegate void ChangeFocusDelegate();

    private void FocusSearchButton()
    {
        SearchButton.Focus();
    }

    private void ViewInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeFocusDelegate focusDelegate = FocusSearchButton;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, focusDelegate);
    }
```

Comment: I think you meant View when your wrote ViewModel. The simpliest solution is to handle "tab_page _added" event in code-behind where set focus on the button

Comment: You were right - I changed it. Is there a tab_page_added event? I didn't found anything like that. This would be a solution if something like this exists...

Answer (score 1):

This should be work like this (over your defined Initialized event of the UserControl):

```
private void ViewInitialized(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.SearchButton.Focus();
}
```

Comment: As I described above... the Initialized method is only once called! And even then you're solution almost never works :( I will extend my post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the Loaded event on your view and in the event handler method call Focus() on your button.

Comment: Try subscribing to the IsVisibleChanged event and in the event handler, if IsVisible is true, call Focus() on your button.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to bit a bit strange...
IsVisibleChanged ... no reaction
Initialized ... no reaction
Loaded ... no reaction

And then I got the solution. What if the runtime uses the same View for each tab and changes only the data inside to another ViewModel. So the solution is:

```
    private void SameViewButDataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeFocusDelegate focusDelegate = FocusFileSearchButton;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, focusDelegate);
    }
```

And each time I add a tab the focus is switched to the Search button.